# Graphical reporting for Selenium Webdriver and TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, reporting

I've been using `TestNG` with `Selenium webdriver`, but the `TestNG` default reports are quite basic in format. I want to have more user friendly and graphical reports. I've tried using `ATU` reporter, but it's giving some error.

Can any one please suggest on same?

Comment: Why don't you try [Report Ng](http://reportng.uncommons.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Another option can be use of [ExtentReports](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/version2/docs.html),  which has screenshots, sample code for you to follow and implement into your selenium project. Also you can have a look at online [sample report](http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ExtentReports2/ExtentJava.html).

[image]

Another feature, if you want to see a comparison of more than one report, you can use [ExtentMerge](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/extentmerge/docs.html) with usage documentation. You can have a look at merged online [sample report](http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ExtentReports2/ExtentMerge.html).

[image]

Comment: Hello, can we also generate reports in excel format using ExternReports ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom report if you wish by implementing the following interfaces of TestNG.

1. IReporter  - Generate report after all the test suites have been run. Basically implementing this will give you a consolidated report.
2. ITestListener - Implementing this, you can create report for individual test runs or simply output the status of your test run during batch execution.

Tutorials here - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_custom_reporter.htm

If you want a ready bake solution you can use ReportNG (http://reportng.uncommons.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful reporting with realtime report of any running test is possible using RealTime report plugin. Very easy to use and no modification needed in existing code, for details please visit this github url [RealTimeReport](https://github.com/startingwithseleniumwebdriver/RealTimeReport)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at [Allure](https://github.com/allure-framework) framework.

It can be used with Maven, Ant or Gradle being integrated with TestNG.
Steps:

- Add AllureTestListener to TestNG settings.
- Add AspectJ Weaver dependency and its properties.
- Run tests.

In case you're using Maven:

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>{latest-allure-version}</allure.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <!--only for 1.3.* TestNG adapters. Since 1.4.0.RC4, the listener adds via ServiceLoader-->
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then, run the build:

```
mvn clean test
```

You can find more about the Allure Core [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/TestNG), some examples of it's usage [here](https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example), and an example of how the report looks like [here](http://ci.qatools.ru/job/allure-core_master-deploy/Allure_report/).